# Calculating the average user presence in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with two columns, `days`, indicating the number of days a user has been seen and `users` , counting the users seen for that many days.

```
+----+---------------+
|days|number_of_users|
+----+---------------+
|   2|           3922|
|   3|           1750|
|   4|            883|
|   5|            563|
|   6|            319|
|   7|            157|
|   8|             79|
|   9|             31|
|  10|              9|
|  11|              2|
+----+---------------+
```

Users seen for 2 days (here 3922) are not seen for 3,4 etc. So each bucket contains a unique set of users. 
How can I calculate the average user presence from this dataframe?

I am thinking of something like taking a `sum_i[users(i)*days(i)] / 30` , where 30 is the total number of days in the month. However I am not sure how I can do this, or if it is the correct formula.

EDIT: AVERAGE USER PRESENCE refers to the average number of days a user is seen, for example, from the above table, something like 3.5 days.

Comment: thanks for that, any idea how I can apply this directly on the dataframe, using its columns?

Comment: It should be sum_i[users(i)*days(i)] / sum_i[users(i)], as you are taking a weighted mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Average user presence in number of days will be the weighted mean `sum_i[users(i)*days(i)] / sum_i[users(i)]`-

```
#Create the DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, sum
df = spark.createDataFrame([(2,3922),(3,1750),(4,883),(5,563),(6,319),(7,157),(8,79),
                            (9,31),(10,9),(11,2)], schema = ['days','number_of_users'])

#Calculating the weighted mean.
df = df.withColumn('Dummy',lit('Dummy'))
df = df.groupBy('Dummy').agg((sum(col('number_of_users') * col('days'))/sum(col('number_of_users'))).alias('avg_user_presence')).drop('Dummy')
df.show()
+------------------+
| avg_user_presence|
+------------------+
|3.0430330524951392|
+------------------+
```

**Cross check:**

```
(2*3922+3*1750+4*883+5*563+6*319+7*157+8*79+9*31+10*9+11*2)/(3922+1750+883+563+319+157+79+31+9+2)
= 23477/7715
= 3.0403
```